# Open HTTPS website on the same iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, https, hyperlink

Im trying to control the navigation of a secure website inside an iframe using links but it keeps opening in a new tab or window. It works normally in a nonsecure website. Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" onclick=window.open("https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463/Product/OND/VBD50BK/","iframe1");>Binders</a>
<a href="#" onclick=window.open("https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463/Product/UPG/BLU113/","iframe1");>Folders</a>

<iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463" style="min-height: 1100px;height:100%; min-width: 600px; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will work, just make sure iframe's javascript code loads from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

```
<a href="https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463/Product/OND/VBD50BK/" target="iframe1">Binders</a>
<a href="https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463/Product/UPG/BLU113/" target="iframe1">Folders</a>

<iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www2.ecinteractiveplus.com/0463" style="min-height: 1100px; height:100%; min-width: 600px; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the help but it still didnt work.
Tested here: jsfiddle.net/c09rL1z4

Comment: That code works, it is opening in a different window because "you can't access an <iframe> with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: That explains everything. Do you have any alternative suggestion for this? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well under development if you are using linux/unix you can edit your /etc/hosts file and change localhost to the domain you need, under production just make sure to run the application on the same origin, in my answer there's a link to same origin policy docs.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!